# Асинхронные запросы в Redux и React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, асинхронность, redux

Здравствуйте, изучаю Redux и React, смотрю примеры. И возник один вопрос: где необходимо делать асинхронный вызов: в `Actions` или в `middleWare`. В чем разница?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если коротко: вы можете делать это "вручную" в каждом action или же написать/использовать middleware, который это процесс как-то автоматизирует.

Общая картина в случае с middleware такая: вы передаете в action все входные данные для запроса и какой-то признак, что нужно сходить на сервер, а логику взаимодействия с сервером пишите один раз общую для всех случаев.

Comment: Есть очень хороший пост о создании такого Middleware https://medium.com/@kadmil/promised-way-to-async-flows-with-redux-43977eef9f46

Добавьте в ответ, пожалуйста.